# How to import GoogleAnalytics header into a library Framework?

Tags: swift, xcode

I create a library framework for my project and I want the framework to be able to depend on Google Analytics library. How do I import the headers into the framework because unlike an app target, framework doesn't have a bridging header? And importing the Google Analytics headers inside the framework's public header file will give other unexpected errors (include of non-modular header inside framework module).

Comment: Hi man, have you any solution for it? please post.

Answer (score -2):

HI you can add  Pod of Google Analytics 
then you can use of this in your app 
 add pod click the link below and follow the steps.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

Hope it helps.