# Import GoogleAnalytics headers into a Swift Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics

It's the repetition of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176250/how-to-import-googleanalytics-header-into-a-library-framework) without a correct answer. I try to add Google Analytics to my framework, but it's not working. The umbrella header file have the error on `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`: "include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FrameworkName': '/Users/.../Pods/Headers/Public/Google/Google/Analytics.h'"

*Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules* is **YES**.
Umbrella header is **Public**.
What else? I spent two days searching for an answer with no result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it.
First I replaced the 'Google/Analytics' pod to the 'GoogleAnalytics' (without slash) because the first is deprecated.
Second in the project where I'm using my framework, in it bridging file I set follow:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"'
```

instead of `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`

Third I removed *GoogleService-Info.plist* file from the project and add GUI tracker ID setup to code, as described in Google [documents](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift).
Done.